# Updating Sharepoint Calendar events + c#

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calendar

How can we update a sharepoint calendar without overlapping an existing event?
Say, the calendar list already has an event with EventDate - 25/Aug/2013 4:00:00 and 26/Aug/2013 15:00:00 . Now, how can I insert a new event without overlapping an already existing event?

Note: I am able to insert items to Calendar using C# code. But, I just need to know whether there is a way to insert the events without overlapping.

Comment: What have you tried until now? I think in this forum you can not write a task and somebody does the coding for you. F.e. have you tried doing a caml query an check all events start and end date on this target day?

Comment: The idea behind posting the question was not to obtain a code, it was to get some suggestions on preventing an overlap. The caml query would fetch all the values within a start and end date. But that would be of little help if the dates which I am providing falls within an already existing period for which an event is raised.

Comment: If I understood you in the right way: you want to find all existing events in the calendar. Find the slots between each event and check if the new event falls into one of these slots?